# Regular expression transcription

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to translate this: `http://*myurl*/feedback.php?rcode=1307954819&lang=it`

in

```
http://*myurl*/index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=feedback&id=1307954819
```

Can someone help me ? :)

#### Edit:

I have to write it in `.htaccess` so I need rewrite rules.

Comment: Where do you take the option and module params from?

Comment: Option is standard. Is option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# mark / as a root
RewriteBase /

# rewrite feedback.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rcode=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^feedback.php$ index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=feedback&id=%1 [L]
```

The rule above will rewrite `/feedback.php?rcode=1307954819&lang=it` into `/index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=feedback&id=1307954819` **without** changing URL in address bar of the browser.

If you need to change URL in address bar as well (to make a redirect) then change `[L]` into `[R=301,L]`

Comment: echo.php ... maybe you want to write "index" ? @LazyOne

Comment: @DonCallisto Yes, `index.php` -- I forgot to change it while I was testing it on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need RegEx for this.
You can use str_replace.

```
$URL='http://myurl/feedback.php?rcode=1307954819&lang=it';

$newURL=str_replace(array('http://myurl/feedback.php','?rcode=','&lang=it'),array('http://myurl/index.php','?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=feedback&id=',''),$URL);
```

Comment: I have to write it in .htaccess so i need rewrite rules :( and "myurl" is something like (booking.x.y) and have to be transcribed in (index.x.y.)

Comment: Oh, ok. You need RegEx for that. :)

Comment: if this is an http rewrite rule (for apache?) you should change the question (and the tags) accordingly to have more accurate answers

Comment: Have you looked at Lumbendil's answer? It looks about right. The .htaccess part.

Comment: Mind that you have to set `RewriteEngine on` first, then the RewriteRule.

Comment: Ok... i've took a look.. But the first part of url have to change from "booking.x.y" (for example) in "index.x.y"

Answer (score 1):

Without taking into acount option amd module params:

```
$url = 'http://*myurl*/feedback.php?rcode=1307954819&lang=it';

echo preg_replace('%^http://([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.php\?rcode=([0-9]*).*$%','http://$1/index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=$2&id=$3',$url);
```

In **.htaccess** it should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^.]*)\.php\?rcode=([0-9]*).*$ /index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but one more question: "myurl" is something like (booking.x.y) and have to be transcribed in (index.x.y.) ;)

Comment: The myurl part isn't changed. This rewrite rule redirects booking.php to index.php?task=booking (and it sets all the other params aswell).

Comment: @Lumbendil : ok but i need to change that :)

Comment: @Lumbendil Since when `RewriteRule` start working with Query string part directly? That rule will not work.

Comment: @LazyOne: it doesn't work in fact .... Do you have any idea ? edit: the first part of url isn't more a problem... So take a look at the original question that is the actual.

Comment: @LazyOne It isn't working directly with Query String, it modifies all the request, but not the host.

Comment: @Lumbendil Well .. accordingly to the rule you wrote (this part `\?rcode=([0-9]*).*` ) you expecting it to work. RewriteRule works with **path part of URL only** (whatever the proper name for this is) -- in this case the path = `feedback.php` that's it.

Comment: It'd need to use RewriteCond as showed here:http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/. I don't have time now to fix it, so if no correct answer has been given when I get home, I'll fix this.

Answer (score 0):

My example is in C# (not a php developer), but the regex pattern should work in both languages..

```
void Main()
{
    string input = @"http://myurl/feedback.php?rcode=1307954819&lang=it";

    Regex pattern = new Regex(".+?&?rcode=([^&]+)");

    string output = pattern.Replace(input, @"http://myurl/index.php?option=com_cake&module=lodgings&task=feedback&id=$1");

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```